# In R, pass a vector of functions to a another function and refer to each passed function by name

Tags: r, function, substitution

I would like to send a group of functions (a list or a vector) to another function and then within that other function I would like to obtain the names of those individual functions I sent.  I also want to use those functions but that seems to be working ok.

For instance:

```
funcA <- function(x,y){z=x+y}
funcB <- function(x,y){z=x-y}

myfunc <- function(x,y,funclist=c(funcA, funcB)){
func1 <- deparse(substitute(funclist[1]))
}
```

What I would like func1 to equal is "funcA" but in this example it equals "funclist[1]".  If I replace the list with a single function name, such as

```
myfunc <- function(x,y,funclist=funcA){
func1 <- deparse(substitute(funclist))
}
```

then I get func1 equals "funcA".  I think my shortcoming is in the understanding of deparse(substitute()) but I'm wondering if there's another method I'm overlooking.

Comment: The challenge is to subset the `funclist` vector without evaluating its elements. There might be a way with some cajoling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
funcA <- function(x,y){z=x+y}
funcB <- function(x,y){z=x-y}

myfunc <- function(x,y,funclist=c(funcA, funcB)){
  func.vec <- as.character(substitute(funclist))
  func1 <- func.vec[2]
  print(func1)
  func2 <- func.vec[3]
  print(func2)
}

myfunc(1,2, c(funcA,funcB))
[1] "funcA"
[1] "funcB"
```

Comment: This evaluates the function but doesn't provide the output desired which is `"funcA"`. And if it isn't possible, guidance on why it isn't.

Comment: @PierreLafortune is this what you want? I'm really sorry that I didn't check your desired output earlier

Comment: The OP is asking why they are having trouble subsetting `funclist[1]` within the function.

Comment: I guess OP's question has been answered. He wanted the function name passed on as argument to be saved as a string. If not please share an example of function call and output that you want.

Comment: This sounds like exactly what I need.  Never thought of using as.character(substitute()).  Thanks!